How to use Flux or Publisher as input to Micronaut HttpClient
It is required to "upload" a programmatically generated Content-type: text/csv using HTTP PUT. The content might be large and it is not desired to store the entire content in memory at any given time. I am trying to use a low-level HttpClient for this.
I was able to find some hints that this might be allowed 1, 2.
I have some code that sends JSON requests to some server and I've tweaked it to do the following:
    var req = HttpRequest.POST(uri, Flux.just(jsonString));  // Was plain jsonString
    req.contentType(contentType)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .bearerAuth(context.getAccessToken());

    return Mono.from(client.exchange(req, String.class));

When I ran the code against a real server, I got a read timeout. The original code works correctly.
I changed Flux.just(jsonString) to Mono.just(jsonString), but got the same error. Note that the real use case I am angling for is with text/csv content-type, but this was easy to quickly check.
Doing some tracing, it looks like there is no POST body when Flux/Mono arguments are used and that the Flux is never subscribed to.
Because of all the magic and the abstractions, it is really not clear what's wrong. I expected Mono.just(jsonString) to work without issue.
Even if it did work, I can't use Mono because I need to generate the csv content row by row or in small batches. The resulting body should be the concatenation of all strings in the Flux, not a JSON array. I don't know what is the impact of Flux<String> on the request body vs. Mono, because it is not documented. Similarly, I don't know how, if at all, content-type impacts requests with body type of String.class.
I have also tried a version where a Flux<byte[]> is used, with same results.
Can you please explain how all this works (or does not)?
Not that the server and protocol cannot be changed.
Using Micronaut v3.10.1
